# How to Count same elements or a specific criteria in one column using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm new in programming, and wanna try to calculate How many males and females in my sql database!
Thanks!

```
try
        {
            string stmt = "SELECT COUNT (Gender) FROM info where Gender is Male ";
            //string stmt = "SELECT COUNT (Gender) FROM info where Gender is Female ";
            int count = 0;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, con);
                {
                    con.Open();
                    count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            label1.Text = "There are " + count.ToString() + " Male in your database";
            //label2.Text = "There are " + count.ToString() + " Female in your database";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Does that code work?  Are you asking for a way that does something specific, or does the above code not work?  If the code doesn't work, what does your data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find both in a single query:

```
try
{
    string stmt = "SELECT SUM(case when Gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) AS MaleCount, 
                          SUM(case when Gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) AS FemaleCount 
                   FROM info";
    int mcount = 0;
    int fcount = 0;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, con);
        {
            con.Open();
            SQLDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                mcount = (int) reader["MaleCount"];
                fcount = (int) reader["FemaleCount"];
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    label1.Text = "There are " + mcount.ToString() + " Male in your database";
    label2.Text = "There are " + fcount.ToString() + " Female in your database";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to know what values are in the Gender column. Is it 'Male' and 'Female', 'M' and 'F', 1 and 2 (in this example, I assume a numeric column) or something else? If it were 'Male' and 'Female' your SQL statement could look like

```
SELECT COUNT (Gender) FROM info where Gender = 'Male'
```

Try the SQL statement out in SQL Server Management Studio. When the results look correct, move it into your C# code. When you do move it to your C# code, make sure you do not accept any input from a user interface as part of your query. If you need the user to be able to affect the query, read about parameterized queries to avoid introducing a huge security issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try this SQL statement

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) people,
        Gender
   FROM info
  GROUP BY Gender
```

It will give you back two rows, one with a count of `Female`, and the other with a count of `Male` rows.

ExecuteScalar is the wrong method for this sort of thing. You need to use [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) and then read the rows.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(Gender) FROM info where Gender = 'Male'";
//string stmt = "SELECT COUNT(Gender) FROM info where Gender = 'Female'";
```